# Equivalence of Logarithm of Expectation of Power and Expectation of Logarithm for a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits

Does the following equality hold? Does it need any further assumptions?

$$
\lim _{s \rightarrow 0} \log \left(\mathbb{E}\left[X^s\right]^{\frac{1}{s}}\right)=\mathbb{E}[\log (X)]
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a non-negative random variable such that $\mathbf{E}[X^{\epsilon}] < \infty$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Then $\mathbf{E}[\log X]$ exists in $[-\infty, \infty)$ and
>
> $$ \lim_{s \to 0^+} \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} = \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X]). $$

**Remark.**

1. In this theorem, we allow $X$ to take values in $[0, \infty]$, with the understanding that $\log 0 = -\infty$ and $\log\infty = \infty$.
2. If the condition $\mathbf{E}[X^{\epsilon}] < \infty$ is dropped, the conclusion of the theorem need not hold. Indeed, let $X$ have a density of the form
   $$f(x) = \frac{2}{x(\log x)^3} \mathbf{1}[x \geq e].$$
   Then $ \mathbf{E}[X^s] = \infty$ for all $s > 0$ but $\mathbf{E}[\log X] = 2$. Hence
   $$ \lim_{s \to 0^+} \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} = \infty > e^2 = \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X]). $$

---

**Proof of Theorem.** Let $X$ be as in the theorem, and let $Y = \log X$.

> **Claim 1.** $\mathbf{E}[\log X]$ exists in $[-\infty, \infty)$.

*Proof.* Using the inequality $e^x \geq 1 + x$, we get $\log X \leq \frac{X^{\epsilon} - 1}{\epsilon}$. Since the right-hand side is integrable, the desired conclusion follows. $\square$

> **Claim 2.**  $ \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} \geq \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X])$ for any $s > 0$. In particular, we have
>
> $$ \liminf_{s \to 0^+} \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} \geq \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X]). $$

*Proof.* For each interval $I = [a, b]$, let $X_I$ and $Y_I$ be the truncated variable defined by

$$ X_I = e^{Y_I}, \qquad Y_I = \operatorname{mid}\{a, Y, b\} = \begin{cases} b, & Y > b, \\ Y, & Y \in I, \\ a, & Y < a. \end{cases} $$

Then by Jensen's inequality, we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[X_I^s] = \mathbf{E}[\exp(s Y_I)] \geq \exp(s\mathbf{E}[Y_I]) = \exp(s\mathbf{E}[\log X_I]). $$

Taking $\frac{1}{s}$-th power to both sided, we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[X_I^s]^{1/s} \geq \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X_I]). $$

Then the desired claim follows by letting $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$. $\square$

> **Claim 3.** We have
> $$ \limsup_{s \to 0^+} \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} \leq \exp(\mathbf{E}[\log X]). $$

*Proof.* Let $Y_+ = \max\{0, Y\}$. Then by Tonelli's theorem,

\begin{align*}
\infty > 1 + \mathbf{E}[X^{\epsilon}]
&\geq \mathbf{E}[\exp(\epsilon Y_+)]
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon^k}{k!} \mathbf{E}[Y_+^k].
\end{align*}

Now fix $N > 0$ and let $Y_N = \max\{-N, Y\}$. From the above estimate, it is easy to deduce that

$$ R(s) := \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{s^{k-2}}{k!}\mathbf{E}[Y_N^k] $$

converges absolutely for all $|s| < \epsilon$, hence $R(s)$ defines an analytic function in this regime. In particular, $R(s)$ is continuous in $|s| < \epsilon$, so we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[e^{s Y_N}]^{1/s}
= (1 + s \mathbf{E}[Y_N] + s^2 R(s))^{1/s}
\to \exp(\mathbf{E}[Y_N]) $$

as $s \to 0^+$. Since $X \leq e^{Y_N}$, this then implies

$$ \limsup_{s \to 0^+} \mathbf{E}[X^s]^{1/s} \leq \exp(\mathbf{E}[Y_N]). $$

Now the desired conclusion follows by letting $N \to \infty$. $\square$

$\blacktriangleright$ **Conclusion.** The desired theorem follows by combining Claim 1 through 3.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $X>0$ almost surely and $\mathbb{E}[\max(|X|^{s_0},1)|\ln(X)|]<+\infty$ for some $s_0>0$.

Since for all $s \in [0,s_0]$,
$$\Big| \frac{\partial}{\partial s}(X^s) \Big|= |X^s \ln(X)| \le \max(|X|^{s_0},1)|\ln(X)|,$$
Legesgue dominated convergence theorem applies and
$$\forall s \in [0,s_0],~
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \Big(\mathbb{E}[X^s]\Big) = \mathbb{E}[X^s\ln(X)].$$
In particular, $$\mathbb{E}[X^s] = 1 + s\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)] + o(s) \text{ as } s \to 0+,$$
so
$$\ln(\mathbb{E}[X^s]) = s\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)] + o(s) \text{ as } s \to 0+,$$
$$(1/s)\ln(\mathbb{E}[X^s]) = \mathbb{E}[\ln(X)] + o(1) \text{ as } s \to 0+,$$
$$(\mathbb{E}[X^s])^{1/s} = \exp(\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]) + o(1) \text{ as } s \to 0+.$$

A similar condition can be obtained to ensure the convergence as $s \to 0-$.